# Redirect Strapi admin index to admin login

Tags: redirect, routes, admin, strapi

I am currently looking for way to create a permanent 301 redirect from the default Strapi admin index route (ie `strapidomain.com`) to the configured admin route (ie `strapidomain.com/admin`).

I have explored utilizing a custom middleware by configuring the admin package:

Path: `./admin/middlewares/redirect/index.js`

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = strapi => {
  return {
    initialize: function(cb) {
      strapi.router.get('/', (ctx) => {
        ctx.redirect(strapi.config.get('server.admin.url', '/admin'))
      });
    }
  };
};
```

I then activated the custom middleware with:

Path: `./admin/config/middleware.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  settings: {
    redirect: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I can still hit the admin panel route without being redirected. Based on everything I have read, this should be possible however I have not been able to get this working.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only issue here is that you just placed the redirect middleware within a `admin` folder which was absolutely not required. The `middlewares` folder should directly reside at the root of your project.

**Correct the path from**:
`./admin/middlewares/redirect/index.js`

**To this:**
`./middlewares/redirect/index.js`

I can show you what I've tried personally, below:

##### My implementation:

**1.** Create a directory in the root of your project
`$ mkdir -p ./middlewares/redirector/`

**2.** Create a `index.js` file in `./middlewares/redirector/` with the content as:

```js
module.exports = () => {
  return {
    initialize() {
      strapi.router.get('/', (ctx) => {
        ctx.redirect(strapi.config.get('server.admin.url', '/admin'));
      });
    },
  };
};
```

**3.** Finally enable the redirector middleware in the `config/middleware.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  settings: {
    redirector: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 6):

for newer version v4+

**src/middlewares/redirector.js**

```js
module.exports = (config, {strapi}) => {
  return async (ctx, next) => {
    if (ctx.path === '/') {
      ctx.redirect(strapi.config.get('server.admin.url', '/admin'));
      return
    }
    await next()
  };
};
```

**config/middlewares.js**

```js
module.exports = [
  {name: 'global::redirector'},
  //...
]
```